# Tastypie error while updating - field has was given data that was not a URI, not a dictionary-alike and does not have a 'pk' attribute

Tags: django, api, rest, tastypie

I keep getting this error when i try to update my resource.

The resource I am trying to update is called Message.
It has a foreign key to account:

```
class AccountResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Account.objects.filter()
        resource_name = 'account'
        '''
        set to put because for some weird reason I can't edit 
        the other resources with patch if put is not allowed.
        '''
        allowed_methods = ['put']
        fields = ['id']


    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['firstname'] = bundle.obj.account.first_name   
        bundle.data['lastname'] = bundle.obj.account.last_name
        return bundle
```

```
class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    account = fields.ForeignKey(AccountResource, 'account', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = AccountMessage.objects.filter(isActive=True)
        resource_name = 'message'
        allowed = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'post']
        authentication = MessageAuthentication()
        authorization = MessageAuthorization()   
        filtering = {
                     'account' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
                     }
```

Now when i try to update my Message using a PATCH, I get this error:

**Data passed in**: `{"text":"blah!"}`

`The 'account' field has was given data that was not a URI, not a dictionary-alike and does not have a 'pk' attribute: <Bundle for obj: '<2> [nikunj]' and with data: '{'lastname': u'', 'id': u'2', 'firstname': u'', 'resource_uri': '/api/v1/account/2/'}'>.`

**Bad Solution:**:

Pass in the data: `{"text":"blah!", "account":{"pk":2}}`
I dont want to pass in the account. I just want to edit the text and nothing else. Why is there a need to pass in the account too?

I tried to use:

```
def obj_update(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
        return super(ChartResource, self).obj_update(bundle, request, account=Account.objects.get(account=request.user))
```

*BUT it doesnt work!!* 
**HELP!**

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using a PUT method, Tastypie expects the 'account' field within the bundle.data object when you are calling the obj_update method.

Also the keyword arguments in obj_update are **not** used to set values like in obj_create, they are used to search the object in question. So when you pass on the account=Account... keyword argument, you are simply telling the obj_create method to search within the AccountMessage table and filter by account.

One way to solve this problem is to set the readonly value to True

```
Class MessageResource(ModelResource):
    account = fields.ForeignKey(AccountResource, 'account', full=True,
                                readonly=True)
```

If you need to set the account when you are creating your message, I suggest setting it on  your obj_create method

```
def obj_create(self, bundle, request=None, **kwargs):
    account = Account.objects.get(account=request.user)
    return super(MessageResource,
                 self).obj_create(bundle, request, account=account, **kwargs)
```

This seems like a better solution, since from what I can understand from your code, the account value points to the creator of the message so it should be set by the system and not the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with a Resource that doesn't have full=True in it.  Tastypie has some different expectations for Resources with full=True in them -- mainly that the entire record be included.  I believe this includes the child resources too.